# Как достать из json нужную мне переменную и присовить ее значение к переменной

Tags: php, json

Есть JSON и я хочу получить из него значение status, присвоить это значение переменной $status чтобы потом использовать в условии

JSON который приходит от сервера:

```
{
  "type": "notification",
  "event": "payment.waiting_for_capture",
  "object": {
    "id": "22d6d597-000f-5000-9000-145f6df21d6f",
    "status": "waiting_for_capture",
    "paid": true,
    "amount": {
      "value": "2.00",
      "currency": "RUB"
    },
    "authorization_details": {
      "rrn": "10000000000",
      "auth_code": "000000",
      "three_d_secure": {
        "applied": true
      }
    },
    "created_at": "2018-07-10T14:27:54.691Z",
    "description": "Заказ №72",
    "expires_at": "2018-07-17T14:28:32.484Z",
    "metadata": {},
    "payment_method": {
      "type": "bank_card",
      "id": "22d6d597-000f-5000-9000-145f6df21d6f",
      "saved": false,
      "card": {
        "first6": "555555",
        "last4": "4444",
        "expiry_month": "07",
        "expiry_year": "2021",
        "card_type": "MasterCard",
      "issuer_country": "RU",
      "issuer_name": "Sberbank"
      },
      "title": "Bank card *4444"
    },
    "refundable": false,
    "test": false
  }
}
```

Код который я пытаюсь заюзать:

```
$source = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$requestBody = json_decode($source, true); 
var_dump($requestBody); 
$status .= $requestBody[status];
if ($status == 'waiting_for_capture' or $status == 'succeeded') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет так:

```
$status = $requestBody['object']['status'];
```

Comment: Все равно не работает...

Comment: "не работает" --- не даёт никакого понятия о проблеме

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482   - смотри что у тебя где и как